# What is meant by "Every number in a reduced residue system $\mod n$ is a generator for the additive group of integers modulo $n$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

What is meant by "Every number in a reduced residue system $\mod n$ **is a generator for the additive group of integers modulo $n$"**? I've no experience with Groups and Abstract algebra.

Comment: Please include the full question in the body of the post. Then go look up the various definitions involved (and then possibly realize that you left out an assumption that $n$ be a prime).

Comment: I've not left out any assumption according to Wikipedia.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system#Facts

Comment: The key to your Question is the meaning of the word "reduced" in the context given by your Comment above.  This really belongs in the Question itself, as "reduced residue system" might mean something different in another context.

Comment: He hasn't left out the assumption that $n$ is prime. In some texts, "reduced residue system mod $n$" refers only to the residue classes of those numbers which are relatively prime to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is that any of the reduced residue system elements $r$ mod $n$ will be a generator of the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  In other words every group element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is expressed as an integer multiple $kr\bmod n$.

More explicitly the set $\{r,2r,\ldots,nr\}$ contains one representative of every residue class mod $n$.

This is because these "reduced residues" $r$ are coprime to $n$, as explained by [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system) you cited in a clarifying Comment:

> Any subset $R$ of the integers is called a reduced residue system modulo $n$ if:
>
> 1. $\gcd(r, n) = 1$ for each $r$ contained in $R$;
> 2. $R$ contains $\varphi(n)$ elements;
> 3. no two elements of $R$ are congruent modulo $n$.

That is, since $r$ and $n$ are coprime, one has for suitable integers $a,b$ that:

$$ ar + bn = 1 $$

Then any residue $k \bmod n$ can be expressed as $kar \bmod n$.

Comment: What is meant by the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It is the additive group of integers modulo $n$.  A group generated by a single element is said to be *cyclic*.  In the finite case you can picture the group elements as being arranged in a cycle, or as the New Math called it, "clock arithmetic".